# Access violation at address 50043a45 in module 'rtl160.bpl'. Read of address 00000000

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Just updated delphi xe2.

The delphi crashes at startup with the error message:

> Access violation at adress 50043a45 in module 'rtl160.bpl'. Read of
>   address 00000000

Tried to reinstall update 3, didn't help. 
Looked in [here](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=450413#450413) and no response.
Reported to Embarcadero, no response.

Any suggestions to how to solve this thing? half a day went to the trash for now.

Comment: "Just updated delphi xe2" and "Reported to Embarcadero, no response." Makes sense. I don't think they fix or even respond to bugs instantly.

Comment: Also, the thread you posted (and probably added the latest reply to) is about another issue, with another update.

Comment: You installed update 4 and encountered this. Is that correct?

Comment: "Reported  to Embarcadero" means you typed a message in the **peer** support forums, right? Wrong. Go to [EMBT Support](http://support.embarcadero.com), and open a support case; installation issues get free support, and you will *then* have reported to Embarcadero. (And no software company with more than a small handful of users provides **instant support** in the middle of the night (in California) to non-reported bugs. :)

Comment: "half a day went to the trash for now." I wouldn't say that, this is experience, next time, wait for the tool to mature if you don't want to waste time.

Comment: 24 hour response to a support request for software that has more than a million users? You **are** kidding, right? You can't get PAID support for most software in 24 hours, especially for software that has tons of users. Maybe you can give your users 24-hour response (I know I could, but I only had 5K users tops), but be serious.

Comment: The link I posted works just fine, BTW. That page has a button on the right side (in a big box captioned "Create A Case" that mentions installation support); click the button, and you get a page asking for the product and version, what you need help with, your email info, and your region. There is no **login** on that page at all.

Comment: This link from the installation group in the EMBT forums might help: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=69859&tstart=0

Comment: @KenWhite if you wnat to get credit for the answer, please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try these 3 things:

1. create a shortcut for the $(delphi)\bin\bde.exe , where  $(Delphi) is C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\ usualy
2. Modify the shortcut that starts your product and add -rfoo to the
   end. Your revised shortcut will look like:

   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\bds.exe" -rfoo
3. If you are on Windows 7 or Vista, right click and Run as Adminstrator

AND AFTER AN HOUR OF WORK, THE EXCEPTION IS BACK. f*** it, I'm throwing this IDE to the garbage.

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks a bunch! What does the switch mean?

Comment: So what changed in that hour? Did you install any third party components? Did you add new units? **Something** made it come back. Think about what you did in that hour. (And please watch your language; while it doesn't bother me, it's not appropriate for forums like this, where it *may* offend people. We try to remain adult here, and adults can choose the appropriate words when they need to do so. Thanks.)

Comment: @loxp, the switch means `use the registry branch "foo" while the IDE is loading`. Since the branch doesn't exist, the IDE will create it and initialize it with the default values (without any settings you've changed or third-party components installed). If this solves the problem, you know it's one of those two things (and it's usually related to buggy third-party components.)

Comment: Also, you missed a step. What you have as #3 is actually step #2, and what you have as 2 is the last part of Step #1.. `Step 3` is "3. Run msconfig. Select Diagnostic Mode. Reboot and see if things work differently. Note that you will want to switch run msconfig again at some point and return to normal mode. Diagnostic Mode typically disables internet connectivity."

Comment: This is a bug in Delphi XE2, not a third party component bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try these 3 things ( 2 first are the same  than before comment ):

1. Create a shortcut for the `$(delphi)\bin\bde.exe`, where `$(Delphi)` is `C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\` usually
2. Modify the shortcut that starts your product and add -rfoo to the end. Your revised shortcut will look like:
   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\bds.exe" -rfoo`
3. Start the shortcut one time.
   With regedit find `HKEY_CURRENT\Software\Enbarcadero\foo`.
   and replace all `HKEY_CURRENT\Software\Enbarcadero\BDS` by `HKEY_CURRENT\Software\Enbarcadero\foo`
   (you can rename BDS by BDS_Old and after foo by BDS).

   After that all works properly without shortcut